# animation css3 flickering issue in Internet explorer 11 with ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

Please take a look at this (https://dev.smartbothub.com/4444/v1/api/Dev-master_bot/getBot) in IE 11.Click on a dropdown button on the right side of the webchat screen on sliding down the webchat flickers.

Here is the css used for animation.

```
.animate-slide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    -webkit-animation: 0.5s slide-up;
    animation: 0.5s slide-up;
}

.animate-slide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    -webkit-animation: 0.5s slide-down;
    animation: 0.5s slide-down;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
    from {
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        height: 80%;
    }
}




@keyframes slide-up {
    from {
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        height: 80%;
    }
}



@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
    from {
        height: 80%;
    }
    to {
        height: 0;
    }
}




@keyframes slide-down {
    from {
        height: 80%;
    }
    to {
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

This only seems to happen in IE11. I'm using angular 1.5 Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you try using **ng-if** instead of **ng-hide**?

Comment: do you use `ng-cloak` directive? It will hide your HTML that hasn't been rendered yet, which could remove the flickering

Comment: @AlekseySolovey sorry this didn't solved issue

Comment: Add  `-ms ` for every `-webkit` in your code.

 `-webkit` (for Webkit browsers, Chrome and Safari)
 `-o` (for Opera)
 `-moz` (for Firefox)
 `-ms` (for IE)

Comment: @Nisarg  According to MS documentation there is nothing called `-ms` Please go through below link  for IE 10+ they have removed it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/06/moving-the-stable-web-forward-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx